# Ruby on Rails Error in rake db:migrate syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

I get this error when I run rake db:migrate
*db/migrate//004_add_data_to_measurement_type_and_measurement_unit.rb:3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
db/migrate//004_add_data_to_measurement_type_and_measurement_unit.rb:3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
db/migrate//004_add_data_to_measurement_type_and_measurement_unit.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'
...celeration' => [{:name =>'m/s²', :si => true, :conversion_f...*

Then I checked it using *$ ruby -wc db/migrate/004_add_data_to_measurement_type_and_measurement_unit.rb* and got the same error.

I was sure that I have all the right gems in place, so I tested by removing the superscript in the line, making it :name =>'m/s' from :name =>'m/s²'. This removed the error.

But **problem is that I need the superscript** and do not know how previous developer managed to run the db:migrate on this. Have you seen something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the superscript is not ASCII.

The previous developer may have set something so that UTF-8 was always assumed, but you should be able to do it for this script specifically by adding the magic comment

```
# coding: utf-8
```

near the top of the script.